# Proving L'Hospital's Rule for $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If f and g are differentiable functions on $(a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\infty$, and I need to prove

(1) if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} g(x) = 0, \lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$

(2) if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} g(x)=\infty$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$.

Here's my attempt at (1). Since I get stuck, and I assume (2) follows a similar strategy, I will only include my attempt at (1).

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\infty\implies \forall M>0\, \exists \delta>0\, st\,\, \forall x\, st\,\, 0<x-a<\delta, \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}>M.$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}}>M$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}}>M$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}>M$

I'd like to just say the following:

$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow a^+} \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)}{g(h)}>M$
but I think this is wrong, since swapping the limits requires $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ to be uniform continuous on $(a,b)$, which it clearly is not.

A different approach is to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ version of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a+} g(x)=0$, but I haven't gotten anywhere with trying to add that information to $ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}>M$

Comment: You can grab any calculus text and see a proof of these.

Comment: What an unhelpful comment. Rudin and Pugh don't cover this case, and I can't find it online anywhere.

Comment: Hey ease up on the tone. I misread the problem, I admit. I thought it was just the ordinary cases of L'Hopital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), define $f(a) = g(a) = 0.$ Then $f,g$ are continuous on $[a,b).$ For $x$ close to $a$ from the right, Cauchy's MVT gives

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)} = \frac{f'(c_x)(x-a)}{g'(c_x)(x-a)} = \frac{f'(c_x)}{g'(c_x)}.$$

As $x\to a^+,c_x \to a^+,$ so by hypothesis the last quotient $\to \infty.$ That gives the result.